# Callback in content.js is trigger too soon in Chrome Extension,

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to scrap linkedin profiles and download as json, using chrome extension.
as everything is work fine
contact information needed to be load asynchronously as, i have to simulate a click and wait contact  info to load in DOM. callback form onMessage is triggered before DOM is loaded properly.
result in incomplete details.
Any help is highly appreciated.

content.js

```
    'use strict';

function getElementByXpath(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
let profileArray = [];
let arrayEducation = [];
let arrayExp = [];
let arrayLanguage = [];
const profile_data = {
   
    
}

let profile_data1 ="";


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message,sender,sendResponse){
   
    if(message === "extension_go"){

    let userName = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1");
       if(userName === null || userName === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{name:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{name:userName.textContent})
       }
       
       
      
    let profilePic = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/button/img");
       let profilePic_src = profilePic.src;
       if(profilePic_src === null || profilePic_src === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{profile_pic:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{profile_pic:profilePic_src});
       }
       
       
    let location = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]");
       if(location === null || location === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{location:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{location:location.textContent.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" ).trim()});
       }
       
       
       
       
    let about = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/div/div[3]/section/div");
       if(about === null || about === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{about:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{about:about.textContent.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" ).trim()});
       }
       
    let designation = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]");
       if(designation === null || designation === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{designation:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{designation:designation.textContent.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" ).trim()});
       }
      
    let company = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/main/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/h2/div");
       if(company === null || company === undefined){
        Object.assign(profile_data,{company:""});
       }else{
        Object.assign(profile_data,{company:company.textContent.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" ).trim()});
       }
       
     
       
    let experience = document.getElementsByClassName("pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view")
        for(let i=0;i<experience.length;i++){
            let experienceStr=experience[i].textContent;
            
            let ExperienceList = experienceStr.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
            let experienceList = ExperienceList.trim();
            
            arrayExp.push(experienceList);
            let ExperienceInfo = Object.assign({}, arrayExp);
            Object.assign(profile_data,{ExperienceInfo:ExperienceInfo});
            
            

    }
    let education = document.getElementsByClassName("pv-profile-section__list-item pv-education-entity pv-profile-section__card-item ember-view")
        for(let i=0;i<education.length;i++){
            let allEducation = education[i].textContent;
            let EducationList = allEducation.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
            let educationList = EducationList.trim();
            
            arrayEducation.push(educationList);
            let educationInfo = Object.assign({}, arrayEducation);
            Object.assign(profile_data,{educationInfo:educationInfo});
           
        }

        let languages = document.getElementsByClassName("pv-accomplishments-block__summary-list-item")
        for(let i=0;i<languages.length;i++){
            let allLanguages = languages[i].textContent;
            let LanguagesList = allLanguages.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
            let languagesList = LanguagesList.trim();
            console.log(languagesList)
            arrayLanguage.push(languagesList);
            let languageInfo = Object.assign({}, arrayLanguage);
            Object.assign(profile_data,{languageInfo:languageInfo});
           
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        document.getElementsByClassName("ember-view link-without-visited-state cursor-pointer text-heading-small inline-block break-words")[0].click()
         
        function waitForElm(selector) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                if (getElementByXpath(selector)) {
                    return resolve(getElementByXpath(selector));
                }
        
                const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
                    if (getElementByXpath(selector)) {
                        resolve(getElementByXpath(selector));
                        observer.disconnect();
                    }
                });
        
                observer.observe(document.body, {
                    childList: true,
                    subtree: true
                });
            });
        }
        waitForElm('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/section/div').then((elm) => {
            var lis = elm.getElementsByTagName("section");
            for(let i=1;i<lis.length+1;i++){
                // console.log(lis[i].getElementsByTagName("h3").textContent);
                let h31 = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/section/div/div/div/section["+i+"]/h3").textContent
                let h32="";
                if(h31 !== null || h31 !== undefined){
                    if(h31.includes("Profile")||h31.includes("Email")||h31.includes("Web")){
                        h32 = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/section/div/div/div/section["+i+"]/div/a").textContent
                    }else if(h31.includes("Phone")){
                        h32 = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/section/div/div/div/section["+i+"]/ul/li/span[1]").textContent
                    }else{
                        h32 = getElementByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/section/div/div/div/section["+i+"]/div/span").textContent
                    }
                }
                let profileDe = h32.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
            let profileDetails = profileDe.trim();
                profileArray.push(profileDetails);
                let contactInfo = Object.assign({}, profileArray);
                Object.assign(profile_data,{contactInfo:contactInfo});

                // console.log(lis[i].getElementsByTagName("div").textContent)
                
            }
           
        });
        sendResponse(profile_data)
}



        
        
        // sendResponse(profile_data)
        
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab) {
    let params = {
        active:true,
        currentWindow:true
    }
    chrome.tabs.query(params,function(tab){
        var CurrTab = tab[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(CurrTab.id,"extension_go",(data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            let data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            var blob = new Blob([data1], {type: "application/json"});
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url
            })
        });
    })
```

manifest.json

```
    {
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name": "Web_Scraper",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "description" : "LinkedIn_WebScraper",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js":["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "downloads"
      ],
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon.png"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    }
}
```